# Simple printing key of a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to print a key from a given hash key but I can't find a simple solution:

```
myhash = Hash.new
myhash["a"] = "bar"

# not working
myhash.fetch("a"){|k|  puts k } 

# working, but ugly
if myhash.has_key("a")?
    puts "a"
end
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Quite unclear. Maybe `my_hash.each{|k, v| puts k}` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't quite understand. If you already know you want to `puts` the value `"a"`, then you only need to `puts "a"`.

What would make sense would be to search for the key of a given value, like so:

```
puts myhash.key 'bar'
=> "a"
```

Or, if it's unknown whether the key exists in the hash or not, and you want to print it only if it exists:

```
puts "a" if myhash.has_key? "a"
```

Comment: hmmm...your 1st paragraph answer does make sense...tnx

Answer (score 18):

To get all the keys from a hash use the [keys](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002866) method:

```
{ "1" => "foo", "2" => "bar" }.keys
=> ["1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an older question, but I think what the original asker was intending was to find the key when he DOESN'T know what it is; For instance, when iterating through the hash.

A couple of other ways to get your hash key:

Given the hash definition:

```
myhash = Hash.new
myhash["a"] = "Hello, "
myhash["b"] = "World!"
```

The reason your first try didn't work:

```
#.fetch just returns the value at the given key UNLESS the key doesn't exist
#only then does the optional code block run.
myhash.fetch("a"){|k|  puts k } 
#=> "Hello!" (this is a returned value, NOT a screen output)
myhash.fetch("z"){|k|  puts k } 
#z  (this is a printed screen output from the puts command)
#=>nil   (this is the returned value)
```

So if you want to grab the key when iterating through the hash:

```
#when pulling each THEN the code block is always run on each result.
myhash.each_pair {|key,value| puts "#{key} = #{value}"}
#a = Hello, 
#b = World!
```

And if you're just into one-liners and want to:

Get the key for a given key (not sure why since you already know the key):

```
myhash.each_key {|k| puts k if k == "a"}
#a
```

Get the key(s) for a given value:

```
myhash.each_pair {|k,v| puts k if v == "Hello, "} 
#a
```